# Why am I getting 'Overlapping instances' error when one doesn't match?

Tags: haskell, state-monad, free-monad

I'm attempting to allow embedding a state monad in my Free monad; here's my simple attempt:

```
{-# language FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Free
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Bifunctor

data Toy state next =
      Output String next
    | LiftState (state -> (next, state))
    | Done

instance Functor (Toy s) where
  fmap f (Output str next) = Output str $ f next
  fmap f (LiftState stateF) = LiftState (first f . stateF)
  fmap f Done = Done

instance MonadState s (Free (Toy s)) where
  state = overState

overState :: (s -> (a, s)) -> Free (Toy s) a
overState = liftF . LiftState

output :: Show a => a -> Free (Toy s) ()
output x = liftF $ Output (show x) ()

done :: Free (Toy s) r
done = liftF Done

program :: Free (Toy Int) ()
program = do
  start <- get
  output start
  modify ((+10) :: (Int -> Int))
  end <- get
  output end
  done

interpret :: (Show r) => Free (Toy s) r -> s -> IO ()
interpret (Free (LiftState stateF)) s = let (next, newS) = stateF s
                                         in interpret next newS
interpret (Free (Output str next)) s = print str >> interpret next s
interpret (Free Done) s = return ()
interpret (Pure x) s = print x

main :: IO ()
main = interpret program (5 :: Int)
```

I get the error:

```
• Overlapping instances for MonadState Int (Free (Toy Int))
    arising from a use of ‘get’
  Matching instances:
    instance [safe] (Functor m, MonadState s m) =>
                    MonadState s (Free m)
      -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Free’
    instance MonadState s (Free (Toy s))
      -- Defined at app/Main.hs:18:10
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: start <- get
  In the expression:
    do { start <- get;
         output start;
         modify ((+ 10) :: Int -> Int);
         end <- get;
         .... }
  In an equation for ‘program’:
      program
        = do { start <- get;
               output start;
               modify ((+ 10) :: Int -> Int);
               .... }
```

As far as I can gather; it's trying to apply this instance:

```
(Functor m, MonadState s m) => MonadState s (Free m)
```

from the
[free package here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-3.4.2/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html); however in this case it would have to match `Free (Toy s)` and there's no `MonadState s (Toy s)` as required so I don't understand why it thinks that it applies.

If I remove my instance definition I get:

```
• No instance for (MonadState Int (Toy Int))
    arising from a use of ‘modify’
```

Which supports my thought that the other instance doesn't actually apply; How can I get this to compile using my specified instance? And can you explain why this is occurring? Is it due to `FlexibleInstances` being used?

Thanks!

Comment: Meta-comment: surely these questions must all be a duplicate of something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance context (the `(Functor m, MonadState s m)` bit) is simply ignored when choosing instances. This is to prevent the compiler from having to do a potentially costly backtracking search to choose an instance. So if two instances apply and one is ruled out only because of an instance context, as in your case, it's an overlap.

This is an unfortunate part of the design of mtl, and one I think each Haskell programmer has bumped up against at some point or other. There's not a lot of choices for fixes; generally you add a newtype and give your instance, as in

```
newtype FreeToy s a = FreeToy (Free (Toy s) a)
instance MonadState s (FreeToy s) where -- ...
```

Comment: That's great to know; but how can I fix it?

Comment: @ChrisPenner Not many choices. I'll add a short bit to my answer.

Comment: The heart of the question is that I'd love to embed state monads inside my Free Monad; so if I can do that cleanly then I'm happy; though it seems like a bit of an oversight if there's no way to get this to work;

Comment: @ChrisPenner You definitely can't embed state monad**s** and use `MonadState` -- the fundep on `MonadState` says that any given monad can only have one type of state. This is important for reducing the number of type annotations needed when using the class methods.

Comment: If I deparameterize the type to just `Toy` and restrict it to `Int` as the state then MonadState should be able to uniquely determine `Toy -> Int`; is that correct? I still have a tough time believing that you can't embed mtl operations in Free; seems like such a useful case! How does everyone else do state inside their Free monads and DSLs? The newtype version doesn't look too bad though so I'll give it a try!

Comment: Newtypes work without too much trouble! I'm still curious as to other discussions around this; so I'm going to leave the question open a bit longer, but this definitely helped! Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisPenner Having *a* state is fine (even when the choice is parameterized as in your example), using a newtype like in this answer. It's just multiple state types that are a problem.